# Service Now web scraping with Selenium (dynamic web scraping)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web, screen-scraping

Does anyone have any workarounds for selecting dynamic content within Selenium?

I have a particular tag that just won't get selected. I have tried selecting the element by: class, link_text, xpath and more. I have tried slowing down the script for every action taken. For example; enter username, wait 10 seconds, select logon, wait 10 seconds, enter password, wait 10 seconds. etc.

The item is clickable manually, but of course my aim is to use automation. Any advice would be welcome. I have attached my code at the point where it breaks. Hope my question makes sense.
Program workflow:

1. Log into service now
2. Open a specific filtered queue of incidents concerning backup logs that are unassigned
3. Process each unassigned backup log in the queue.
4. If there are no logs in the queue, wait 15 minutes and repeat step 3 after refreshing the web browser.

   `def process_asigra_ticket(self):`

- Opens 1 asigra ticket in the unassigned queue and processes it as a service desk agent would do whether erorrs are outputted in a log or not.
- Takes note of the INC for each ticket processed in the unassigned queue and sends a loggin message to a teams channel.
- MS teams channel can later be used for auditing how the script has functioned. If

```
driver = self.driver
```

## while True:

```
 try:
    first_incident = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "linked formlink"))) # code won't select this icon for the life of it 
    time.sleep()
    first_incident.click()
```

I'm receiving the following error message:

> raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Dear Zim, I tried my level best to fix your post so that its intent is clear. Can you please review it now to make sure I've not introducing any error while editing it.

Comment: It could be that the element you are trying to click is "hidden" inside an `iframe` or inside a `shadow-root`. Open the browser inspector tool and search `//iframe`. If it doesn't find anything then try to manually look in the HTML code if you find a `#shadow-root (open)` somewhere

Comment: @RBT My apologies for the output. The change was perfect, I'll ensure to make sure the output for my future questions are legible.